# Calculate the Correlation of two arrays where each array is disjointed

Tags: excel

I have data similar to the following in Excel:

```
             A           B
 1           1,287.90    221,300 
 2           0           0
 3           1,828.93    64,080 
 4           417.81      0
 5           397.37      76,529 
 6           1,371.69    0
 7           1,316.81    50,761 
 8           1,828.93    28,645
```

I want to calculate the correlation coefficient of these two arrays where there are non-zeros. I want to do this without copying the data to a separate sheet with the zeros removed. I have tried this for example:

CORREL({A1,A3,A5, A7:A8}, {B1,B3,B5, B7:B8}) but this does not work. Any ideas

Comment: Have you tried using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to make it an Array Formula?  And / or, entering every cell manually (`CORREL({A1,A3,A5,A7,A8},{B1,B3,B5,B7,B8})`) instead?

Comment: What's your expected output? I've just tried inserting rows with one or two blank values and it didn't affect the result of `CORREL()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you don't have to do nothing:

[image: correlation]

As you can see the correlation result is the same. Did I misunderstand your question?

**Update:** From your comment I suppose the dashed cells on your question may represent zeros and you want to remove those values from the result. If that's the case you could place the formula:

```
{=CORREL(IF(A1:A8*B1:B8<>0;A1:A8);B1:B8)}
```

Don't forget to enter the formula by `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` to place the brackets.

Comment: If you remove the zero values so it is blank then yes you are right. However, I am not able to do this. I need to calculate the correlation whilst the zeros are still in the data

Comment: Do you mean that your cells with a `-` have zeros on your question?

Comment: Yes that works. Thank you so much. (I'm assuming you want commas between your arguments rather than semicolons?)

Comment: Actually, since I'm from Portugal, I really want semicolons... Don't forget to accept my answer!

Comment: Aaaaah ok. No problem